# Remove Rows from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an output like:

```
      Date    Sex  Race                  Cause of Death                     City state
07/17/2012 Female White     1,1-Difluoroethane Toxicity                      NaN   NaN
10/01/2012   Male White                 Heroin Toxicity                 PORTLAND    CT
04/28/2013   Male White           Acute Heroin Toxicity CT(41.575155 -72.738288)   NaN
04/06/2014   Male White Heroin and Cocaine Intoxication                WATERBURY    CT
04/27/2014   Male White       Acute Heroin Intoxication               NEW LONDON    CT
```

My city col has value CT(41.575155  -72.738288), I want to remove this row. How can I do it?

Comment: `City` value is `CT(41.575155 -72.738288)` and `state` value is NaN?

Comment: yes , State-NAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider a city has no number in its name:

```
>>> df[~df['City'].fillna('').str.findall(r'\d').astype(bool)]

         Date     Sex   Race                   Cause of Death        City state
0  07/17/2012  Female  White      1,1-Difluoroethane Toxicity         NaN   NaN
1  10/01/2012    Male  White                  Heroin Toxicity    PORTLAND    CT
3  04/06/2014    Male  White  Heroin and Cocaine Intoxication   WATERBURY    CT
4  04/27/2014    Male  White        Acute Heroin Intoxication  NEW LONDON    CT
```

Step by step:

```
# Convert NaN to '' because NaN is a number :-)
>>> df['City'].fillna('')
0                              
1                    PORTLAND
2    CT(41.575155 -72.738288)
3                   WATERBURY
4                  NEW LONDON
Name: City, dtype: object

# Now find a number in the string
>>> df['City'].fillna('').str.findall(r'\d')
0                                                  []
1                                                  []
2    [4, 1, 5, 7, 5, 1, 5, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 8, 2, 8, 8]
3                                                  []
4                                                  []
Name: City, dtype: object

# Convert to boolean. An empty list return False
>>> df['City'].fillna('').str.findall(r'\d').astype(bool)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: City, dtype: bool

# Invert the mask with ~
>>> ~df['City'].fillna('').str.findall(r'\d').astype(bool)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: City, dtype: bool

# Finally keep the right rows (see the answer)
```

Comment: When i run i dont get the same output as yours

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: 2 04/28/2013 Male White Acute Heroin Toxicity CT(41.575155 -72.738288)

Comment: Your forgot the `~`

Comment: Ohh brilliant, can you explain me more about the entire function? i am student doing this course. Very much new to me